# FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:

Tags: php, nginx, сервер, php7.2

Подскажите пожалуйста, что за ошибка. 
Там где oursite - наш основной домен, host - еще один домен, который смотрит на корень проекта, ip - ip юзверя, который заходил.
Примерно в это время решал вопрос с composer.lock на сервере могло ли это вызвать данную ошибку? 
Сервис по уникальным ссылкам, сейчас все работает никаких действия для фикса не было

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/oursite/vendor/composer/../aws/aws-sdk-php/src/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/oursite/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/oursite/vendor/composer/../aws/aws-sdk-php/src/functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/oursite/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: *ip*, server: host, request: "GET /aXzAJ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "host"
2019/11/20 17:11:20 [error] 11271#11271: *72121 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/oursite/vendor/composer/../aws/aws-sdk-php/src/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/api.qeepmail.ru/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/oursite/vendor/composer/../aws/aws-sdk-php/src/functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/oursite/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66" while reading response header from upstream, client: *ip*, server: host, request: "GET /dqlNT HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "host"
```

Comment: попробуйте сделать `composer dumpautoload` или перекачать заново все библиотеки

Comment: А могла ли эта ошибка привести к неработоспособности функционала на сервере ?

Comment: Очень даже могла